# Create Javascript variable dynamically and use it to fetch corresponding json response

Tags: javascript, json

I am receiving a JSON response from an API like the one shown below:
[image]

However, I am receiving the column_code (underlined in the img) in the `variable_meta` section of the resonse and in the `data` part of the response, the same column_code is the variable name being used to send me time-series data..
Now, I am confused as to how to get the data in such a situation where the variable name is created from the column code and later used to fetch the time-series data.

I have tried using the `window` approach but its not working for me.
In the below code, I want to replace the use of `FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A` with a variable getting created dynamically

```
if( x[i].FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A !=-9999) {
      d = new Date(x[i].date_UTC)
      y.push([d, x[i].FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A])
      //console.log(d, x[i].FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A)
    }
```

Edit :
Pasting the JSON response too as requested by few:

```
{
    "meta_data": {
        "station_meta": [
            {
                "city": "xxx",
                "station": "yyy",
                "lat": 58.992778,
                "lon": 15.844722,
                "height": 277,
                "landcover": "Artificial Surfaces"
            }
        ],
        "variable_meta": [
            {
                "city": "xxx",
                "station": "yyy",
                "variable": "Air Temperature",
                "variable_logger_name": "CS215_AirTemperature_degC_Avg",
                "height": 2,
                "aggregation": "A",
                "level": 2,
                "unit": "ºC",
                "column_code": "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A"
            },
            {
                "city": "xxx",
                "station": "yyy",
                "variable": "Air Temperature",
                "variable_logger_name": "CS215_AirTemperature_degC_Min",
                "height": 2,
                "aggregation": "I",
                "level": 2,
                "unit": "ºC",
                "column_code": "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_I"
            },
            {
                "city": "xxx",
                "station": "yyy",
                "variable": "Air Temperature",
                "variable_logger_name": "CS215_AirTemperature_degC_Max",
                "height": 2,
                "aggregation": "X",
                "level": 2,
                "unit": "ºC",
                "column_code": "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_X"
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "date_UTC": "2018-05-14 11:00:01",
            "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A": -9999,
            "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_I": -9999,
            "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_X": -9999
        },
        {
            "date_UTC": "2018-05-14 12:00:01",
            "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A": -9999,
            "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_I": -9999,
            "FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_X": -9999
        },   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet with the JSON example instead of the image? It would help a lot to test a solution

Comment: does every column value in the variable_meta will have unique value in data array ?

Comment: It seems like your approach is illogical since `meta_data.variable_meta[0]` and `data[0]` are at the same level already.

Comment: What output do you need?  Can you put a sample of what you expect "y" to contain (or whatever the final output should be)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
let response = WHATEVER_YOU_GET_FROM_FETCH; // { meta_data: ..., data: ... }
let column_name = response.meta_data.variable_meta[0].column_name;
let column_value = response.data[0][column_name];

if(x[i][column_value] !=-9999) {
  d = new Date(x[i].date_UTC)
  y.push([d, x[i].FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A])
  //console.log(d, x[i].FRWRTM_AirT_2_2_A)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of all the column_code values from the 3 elements in the variable_meta array

```
const fieldNames = yourData.meta_data.variable_meta.map(vm => vm.column_code);
```

Then, depending on how you need your data structured, iterate your data and the fieldNames array.  For example

```
const fields = fieldNames.map(fn => 
  yourData.data.filter(d => 
    (d[fn] || d[fn] === 0) && d[fn] != -9999
  ).map(d => 
    [new Date(d.date_UTC), d[fn]]
  )
);
```